# Checklist Box Selected Items from LinQ

Tags: linq, asp.net-3.5, linq-to-objects

I am writing the following line of code to extract the selected items in checklistbox.

```
ListItemCollection ChecklistBoxCollection = new ListItemCollection();
            foreach (ListItem ChecklistBoxItem in ChecklistBox.Items)
                if (ChecklistBox.Selected)
                    ChecklistCollection.Add(ChecklistBox);
```

Is there any way to get these items in LinQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no automatic conversion to ListItemCollection, but you can use AddRange to add the selected items at once.  I'm not sure this is much of an improvement and may be slower because AddRange only takes an array.

```
ListItemCollection ChecklistBoxCollection = new ListItemCollection();
ChecklistBoxCollection.AddRange( checklistBox.Items
                                             .Cast<ListItem>()
                                             .Where( i => i.Selected )
                                             .ToArray() );
```

Comment: I think, the reply is according to system.code.ddl in .Net Framework 3.5

Comment: No.  It appears to me that AddRange for ListItemCollection only accepts an array of ListItem, not an IEnumerable of ListItem so you must do the conversion to Array.  If an IEnumerable of ListItem will work, instead of a ListItemCollection, then you can omit the AddRange and ToArray both and just use the `checklistBox.Items.Where(...)`.

Comment: Actually where is not available in Items list. I am using 3.5 ASP.net

Comment: System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList

Comment: You need to throw in a `Cast<ListItem>()` to get an `IEnumerable<ListItem>` that you can use with Where.  I'll update.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4415/discussion-between-pankaj-and-tvanfosson)

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI;
using OceanManager.AuditSystem.ObjectModel;
using OceanManager.AuditSystem.BLL;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

Comment: You need `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

I have been using these extension methods.

```
    public static List<string> GetCheckedValues(this CheckBoxList list)
    {
        var values = new List<string>();
        values.AddRange(from ListItem item in list.Items
                    where item.Selected
                    select item.Value);
        return values;
    }

    public static List<string> GetCheckedTexts(this CheckBoxList list)
    {
        var values = new List<string>();
        values.AddRange(from ListItem item in list.Items
                    where item.Selected
                    select item.Text);
        return values;
    }
```